# Unable to get the value of hidden field via jquery using serialize() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serialization

I'm using the [Tag Manager plugin](https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager) to create tags for my form and passing values to php using the serialize() function in jquery. When I retrieve the value I get an empty string but without the serialize() function, the tag creator works fine.

```
<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input form-control tm-input-info" id="collaborationsSoughtInput" name="collaborationsSoughtInput" />
```

And this is my jquery function

```
function adduser() {
    $.post("functions/add-user.php", $("#registerForm").serialize()).done(function(data) {
      var result = $.trim(data);
      if (result == "OK") {
        window.location.href = "login";
      } else {
        console.log("Register error :" + result);
      }
    });
  }
```

And the php code

```
  $collaborationsSoughtInput = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['hidden-tags']);
```

And here is the working [example](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/bootstrap-input-multiple-tags-example-using-tag-manager-jquery-pluginexample.html)

Here if the complete form

```
<form action="" id="registerForm" class="mb-4" style="margin-bottom: 50px" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback row">
    <label for="fullnameInput" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" required>Full Name *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>
    </div>
    <span id="fullNameError" class="color-red hide-me">Full Name Error</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback row">
    <label for="usernameInput" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input minlength="4" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
    </div>
    <span id="usernameError" class="color-red hide-me">Userame Error</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback row">
    <label for="passwordInput" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" required>Password *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" value="hunter2" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <span id="passwordError" class="color-red hide-me">Password Error</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="collaborationsSoughtInput">Collaborations Sought *</label><br/>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input form-control tm-input-info" id="collaborationsSoughtInput" name="collaborationsSoughtInput" />
    </div>
    <span id="collaborationsError" class="color-red hide-me">Collaborations Error</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

And in the console, I get this

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: hidden-tags in ...
```

Comment: the name is "tags" not "hidden-tags"

Comment: The hidden-tags is created automatically by the tag manager plugin. This is the only way to get the value the user enters. I tried without serialize() function and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole output of .serialize() is empty? Seems like your form selector could be wrong then.

Comment: No, other values of the form is fetched except the tag part.

Comment: Are you sure the <input> element is within the form? Seems odd if serialize don't pick it up.

Comment: Yes, the input is inside the form.